# Convert query result into array in shell script

Tags: string, shell

I am trying very simple thing using shell script on `BASH` shell. I am trying to get keyids of all Users into an array in a shell script. I will later loop them for further processing.

I wrote very simple code. But I am stuck while converting a space separated QUERY_RESULTS string into an array.

I tried various options e.g. `set -A` , `read -a`, `array=( $ QUERY_RESULTS } )` etc. 
Nothing is working for me. Every-thing I try, gives me some error.

For e.g.

- `set -A` gives me `illegal option -A`.
- `read -a` also gives me `illegal option -a`.
- `array=( $ QUERY_RESULTS } );` gives me `( unexpected`.

Below is my code. Please help me here.

```
#IFS="";
echo "Get list of Active Users from Table ";
QUERY_RESULTS=$( mysql -u username password -e "SELECT keyid from users where isActive = 1" );
echo $QUERY_RESULTS;
#eval `read -a arr <<$QUERY_RESULTS`;
#array=( $ QUERY_RESULTS } );
echo $array;
```

Comment: Does your shell support arrays? Which shell is this?

Comment: That seems unlikely because bash's `read` does support `-a`.

Comment: Your question gave me hints, but ultimately I need more. If you want to capture the result of a MySql query into an array, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061108/470749

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this:

```
read -r -a array <<< $QUERY_RESULTS
```

Note the "<<<" instead of "<<"

If the contents of QUERY_RESULTS consist of multiple lines you may want to do it this way:

```
mapfile -t array <<< $QUERY_RESULTS
```

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve my target using following code. However still I am having problem in converting QUERY RESULT to string.

```
echo "Get list of Active Users from Table ";
QUERY_RESULTS=$( mysql -u username password -e "SELECT keyid from users where isActive = 1" );

for i in `echo $QUERY_RESULTS | tr ' ' '\n' |sed  '1d' | tr '\n' ' '`
do
sh doAction.sh $i;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can get the array and string as below:

```
query="SELECT keyid from users where isActive = 1;" 
QUERY_RESULTS=($(mysql -u username password -e "$query"))
```

or

```
QUERY_RESULTS=(`mysql -u username password -e "$query"`)
QUERY_RESULTS_STR=$(printf "%s," "${QUERY_RESULTS[@]}")
```

Pls do notice that you need the "()" out of the mysql cmd, which make the result a bash array that can be used in a loop. And "%s,", the "," is the delimiter to separate the elements when change to str, you can change to other delimiter if needed.

Comment: Cool, I used your hint here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061108/470749

Comment: @Ryan, great to know this still works and helped you!