# Store mysql result in a bash array variable

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to store MySQL result into a global bash array variable but I don't know how to do it.

Should I save the MySQL command result in a file and read the file line by line in my `for` loop for my other treatment?

Example:

```
user password
Pierre aaa
Paul bbb
```

Command:

```
$results = $( mysql –uroot –ppwd –se  « SELECT * from users );
```

I want that `results` contains the two rows.

Comment: Which "two lines" are you talking about in your last sentence? I might have corrected it, but I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Mapfile for containing whole table into one bash variable

You could try this:

```bash
mapfile result < <(mysql –uroot –ppwd –se  "SELECT * from users;")
```

Than

```bash
echo ${result[0]%$'\t'*}
echo ${result[0]#*$'\t'}
```

or

```bash
for row in "${result[@]}";do
    echo Name:  ${row%$'\t'*}  pass: ${row#*$'\t'}
done
```

**Nota** This will work fine while there is only 2 fields by row. More is possible but become tricky

#### Read for reading table row by row

```bash
while IFS=$'\t' read name pass ;do
    echo name:$name pass:$pass
  done  < <(mysql -uroot –ppwd –se  "SELECT * from users;")
```

#### Read and loop to hold whole table into many variables:

```bash
i=0
while IFS=$'\t' read name[i] pass[i++];do
    :;done  < <(mysql -uroot –ppwd –se  "SELECT * from users;")

echo ${name[0]} ${pass[0]}
echo ${name[1]} ${pass[1]}
```

### New (feb 2018) shell connector

There is a little tool (on [github](https://github.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash)) or on my own site: ([shellConnector.sh](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh) you could use:

#### Some preparation:

```bash
cd /tmp/
wget -q http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh
. shell_connector.sh
newSqlConnector /usr/bin/mysql '–uroot –pspaced\ password'
```

Note: if your password do contain spaces, you have to escaped them. Don't try to enclose with quotes nor double-quotes!

Add `-f` to tell `mysql` to continue after SQL errors.

##### Creating a temporary table for demo:

Once `newSqlConnector` run, they create three *file descriptors*:
`$SQLIN` `$SQLOUT` and `$SQLERR`:

```bash
declare -p ${!SQL*}
```

```
declare -- SQLERR="10"
declare -- SQLIN="60"
declare -- SQLOUT="63"
```

Don't matter...

```bash
cat >&$SQLIN <<eof
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(30), date DATE);
  INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'alice','2015-06-09 22:15:01'),
       (2,'bob','2016-08-10 04:13:21'),(3,'charlie','2017-10-21 16:12:11');
eof
```

##### Then playing with your temporary table:

Ok, then now:

```bash
mySqlReq myarray "SELECT * from users;"
printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}"
```

```
1   alice   2015-06-09
2   bob     2016-08-10
3   charlie 2017-10-21
```

```bash
declare -p ${!myarray*}
```

```
declare -a myarray=([0]=$'1\talice\t2015-06-09' [1]=$'2\tbob\t2016-08-10' [2]=$'3\tcharlie\t2017-10-21')
declare -a myarray_e=()
declare -a myarray_h=([0]="id" [1]="name" [2]="date")
```

This tool are in early step of built... You have to manually clear your variable before re-using them:

```bash
unset myarray
mySqlReq myarray "SELECT name from users where id=2;"
echo $myarray
```

```
bob
```

```bash
declare -p ${!myarray*}
```

```
declare -a myarray=([0]="bob")
declare -a myarray_e=()
declare -a myarray_h=([0]="name")
```

```bash
unset myarray
mySqlReq myarray "SELECT name from users where wrongCol=42;"
```

```
[1]+  Exit 1  coproc COPROC stdbuf -o0 $command "${args[@]}" 2>&$SQLERR
```

From there, the `mysql` client die. You could add `-f` flag to `mysql` command to avoid this. Anyway:

```bash
declare -p ${!myarray*}
```

```
declare -a myarray=()
declare -a myarray_e=([0]="ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 6: Unknown column 'wrongCol' in 'where clause'")
declare -a myarray_h=()
```

Comment: Ok, thx, the two last solution can contains much fields than 2 right ?  in your while loop, it's not i instead i++ ? while IFS=$'\t' read name[i] pass[i++];do

Comment: U could write: `while IFS=$'\t' read name[i] pass[i];do ((i++));done < <(mysql...` if you prefer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're looking to get a global variable inside your script you can simply assign a value to a varname:

   ```
   VARNAME=('var' 'name') # no space between the variable name and value
   ```

   Doing this you'll be able to access VARNAME's value anywhere in your script after you initialize it.
2. If you want your variable to be shared between multiple scripts you have to use export:

   script1.sh:

   ```
   export VARNAME=('var' 'name')
   echo ${VARNAME[0]} # will echo 'var'
   ```

   script2.sh

   ```
   echo ${VARNAME[1]} # will echo 'name', provided that 
                      # script1.sh was executed prior to this one
   ```

NOTE that export will work only when running scripts in the same shell instance. If you want it to work cross-instance you would have to put the export variable code somewhere in .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: For your exact scenario it would be something like results=($(mysql –uroot –ppwd –se « SELECT * from users))

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @F. Hauri seems really complicated.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38052768/470749 helped me realize that I needed to **use parentheses `()` wrapped around the query result to treat is as an array**.

```
#You can ignore this function since you'll do something different.
function showTbl {
    echo $1;
}

MOST_TABLES=$(ssh -vvv -t -i ~/.ssh/myKey ${SERVER_USER_AND_IP} "cd /app/ && docker exec laradock_mysql_1 mysql -u ${DB} -p${REMOTE_PW} -e 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = \"${DB}\" AND table_name NOT LIKE \"pma_%\" AND table_name NOT IN (\"mail_webhooks\");'")
#Do some string replacement to get rid of the query result header and warning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210880/replace-one-substring-for-another-string-in-shell-script
warningToIgnore="mysql\: \[Warning\] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure\."
MOST_TABLES=${MOST_TABLES/$warningToIgnore/""}
headerToIgnore="table_name"
MOST_TABLES=${MOST_TABLES/$headerToIgnore/""}

#HERE WAS THE LINE THAT I NEEDED TO ADD! Convert the string to array:
MOST_TABLES=($MOST_TABLES)
for i in ${MOST_TABLES[@]}; do
    if [[ $i = *[![:space:]]* ]]
    then          
        #Remove whitespace from value https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232433/470749
        i="$(echo -e "${i}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"  
        TBL_ARR+=("$i")
    fi
done
for t in ${TBL_ARR[@]}; do        
    showTbl $t
done
```

This successfully shows me that `${TBL_ARR[@]}` has all the values from the query result.

Comment: I think, my two first solution: **"`mapfile ...`*** and ***Read for reading table row by row*** are both simplier and lignther than your!

Comment: And if solution showing *`connector`* is something *complicated*, they present a way to use *re-usable* staying alive connection, with the ability to use `CREATE TEMP TABLE`, for sample...

Answer (score -1):

```
results=($( mysql –uroot –ppwd –se "SELECT * from users" ))
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
then
  echo fail
  exit
fi
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this solves the problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)