# Use MySQL output as input for BASH function in a loop

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash, function

Let's say I have a MySQL table `animals` with columns `id, name` and 3 rows:

```
1, Mountain Goat
2, Angry Chicken
3, Weird Llama
```

If I run the command `animals=$(mysql -u root -e 'SELECT name FROM animals')`, I get the result `Mountain Goat Angry Chicken Weird Llama`.

If I hard code the animals into the array `animals=("Mountain Goat" "Angry Chicken" "Weird Llama")`, and then try to access the second entry of the array with the command `echo ${animals[1]}`, I get the output `Angry`, not "Angry Chicken".

Ultimately what I want is the pass each value `animals.name` into a function in BASH. See the sample script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
animals=$(mysql -u root -e 'SELECT name FROM animals')
function showAnimal {
    echo "Wow, look at the "$1"!";
}
for i in $animals; do
    showAnimal ${animals[$i]}
done
showAnimal
```

And get the following results:

```
Wow, look at the Mountain Goat!
Wow, look at the Angry Chicken!
Wow, look at the Weird Llama!
```

Comment: Your question gave me hints, but ultimately I need more. If you want to capture the result of a MySql query into an array, you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57061108/470749

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to (incorrectly) treat `animals` as an array when it is a simple variable.

If you run the script with `bash -x` you will see that you are calling the `showAnimal` function with all of the animals as parameters, instead of passing the animals to the function one by one.

All you need to do is to fix the parameter you pass to the `showAnimal` function in your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
animals=$(mysql -u root -e 'SELECT name FROM animals')
function showAnimal {
    echo "Wow, look at the "$1"!";
}
for i in $animals; do
    showAnimal $i
done
```