# Bash script to import the multiple CSV files into a mysql database using load data local infile command

Tags: sql, linux, bash, mysql-workbench

1. I have Multiple CSV files which are stored in one of the folder then I need to use these folder to fetch the csv files then load them into Database Table.
2. This script need to prepare in **Bash** with parameterized fields like InputFolderPath(loop Csv Files), DatabaseConnection, SchemaName, TableName then pass these fields using

   Load Data Local Infile Command.

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service.  It's about help.  Please show your table schema, sample data and your script and query so far

Comment: You could try to use [mysql shell connector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35276157/1765658),,, with [How to parse CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69514496/1765658)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me,

```
for f in /var/www/path_to_your_folder/*.csv
do
    mysql -e "use database_name" -e "
        load data local infile '"$f"' into table your_table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (column_name1, @date_time_variable1, column_name3)
SET some_column_name_which_contains_date = STR_TO_DATE(@date_time_variable1, '%d-%m-%Y');" -u your_mysql_username_here --p --local-infile=1

    echo "Done: '"$f"' at $(date)"

done
```

This script will prompt password for mysql.

i am using this script on ec2 + ubuntu